# Why does setState on onChange does not give Maximum update depth exceeded error

Tags: reactjs, setstate

Why does this code does not give maximum update depth exceeded while we are using setState inside the render method.

```
 class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    name: ""
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      name: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing `}`?

Comment: Why you think it should?...

Comment: @Chris Sorry this is supposed to be just an example. I am having hard time understanding the maximum update exceeded error concept. I guess it's clear now

Comment: @DennisVash Actually since we have setState inside the render method which causes the maximum update exceeded error so I thought. But now I know if use onChange=(this.handleChange()} I am going to get the error but not if I use onChange={this.handleChange}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.handleChange is only called when change happens on the input field. Maximum update depth exceeded only happens if you call the function like this: onChange{this.handleChange()} because it automatically rerender (calling setState) itself and going inside an infinite loop.
You should read about onchange property for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange

Answer (score 0):

Maximum update depth exceeded error only happens if the setState changes something on the page causing a rerender, and that rerender causes another rerender which will go into an infinite loop. setState is contained in the onChange event handler which will not cause an infinite loop, it will only be updated when a user types in it. React can definitely keep up with a user's typing speed and even just smashing the keyboard.